# WP date_query for most downloaded files in last 30 days

Tags: wordpress, date, facetwp

I'm using WP Download manager to track some products and FacetWP for the search filtering. I'm modifying and creating some custom sort options w/FacetWP with no issue. I can't figure out how to modify one using WP's 'date_query'

This one works to sort by most downloaded files (I'm not including the entire filter):

```
options['__wpdm_download_count'] = array(
    'label' => 'Most Popular All Time',
    'query_args' => array(
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '__wpdm_download_count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    )
);
```

However this one doesn't work at all:

```
$options['__wpdm_download_count_30'] = array(
    'label' => 'Most Popular Last 30 Days',
    'query_args' => array(
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '__wpdm_download_count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => '-1 month ago',
                'before' => 'today',
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

I don't feel like the comparison is correct for after and before, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seem to me that:

```
'after' => '-1 month ago',
```

Should be:

```
'after' => '1 month ago',
```

The 'after' accepts strtotime compatible strings. These can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: Good point, I used that but still not modifying the query. Still returns the same as the first block in my original question.